# Assigning same value to a variable yields a different result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, spyder

Whilst coding a game in python I was having a problem with a portion of the code. During some debugging I ran into something really weird which I cannot explain.
The first code which I show prints a certain value to the array 'polygon'. The second code is the same but at the end I assign to the array 'polygon' the value printed by the first code. I would obviously expect the rest of the programme (which I do not show) to act in the same way with the first or second code because they end up giving 'polygon' the same value. Yet the second code makes the rest of the programme to work but the first  doesn't.

For the life of me I cannot figure out what is going on. I don't provide the rest of the programme because I think it would be redundant as it is the same in the first and second case.

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this? Thank you for your help.

## first code:

```
if 1:
    dimensions = 3
    polygon = [[[100,100],[100,-100]],[[100,-100],[-100,-100]],[[-100,-100],[-100,100]],[[-100,100],[100,100]]]
    for limeJuice in range(dimensions-2):
        p = copy.deepcopy(polygon)
        for j in range(len(p)):
            p[j][0].append(100)
            p[j][1].append(100)
        bob = copy.deepcopy(polygon)
        for j in range(len(bob)):
            bob[j][0].append(-100)
            bob[j][1].append(-100)
        q = []
        for j in range(len(p)):
            q.append([p[j][0],bob[j][0]])
        polygon = []
        for pearJuice in p: polygon.append(pearJuice)
        for pearJuice in bob: polygon.append(pearJuice)
        for pearJuice in q: polygon.append(pearJuice)
        print(polygon)

#rest of the programme


#--------------------------------------------------------------------#
#second code:

if 1:
    dimensions = 3
    polygon = [[[100,100],[100,-100]],[[100,-100],[-100,-100]],[[-100,-100],[-100,100]],[[-100,100],[100,100]]]
    for limeJuice in range(dimensions-2):
        p = copy.deepcopy(polygon)
        for j in range(len(p)):
            p[j][0].append(100)
            p[j][1].append(100)
        bob = copy.deepcopy(polygon)
        for j in range(len(bob)):
            bob[j][0].append(-100)
            bob[j][1].append(-100)
        q = []
        for j in range(len(p)):
            q.append([p[j][0],bob[j][0]])
        polygon = []
        for pearJuice in p: polygon.append(pearJuice)
        for pearJuice in bob: polygon.append(pearJuice)
        for pearJuice in q: polygon.append(pearJuice)
        polygon = [[[100, 100, 100], [100, -100, 100]], [[100, -100, 100], [-100, -100, 100]], [[-100, -100, 100], [-100, 100, 100]], [[-100, 100, 100], [100, 100, 100]], [[100, 100, -100], [100, -100, -100]], [[100, -100, -100], [-100, -100, -100]], [[-100, -100, -100], [-100, 100, -100]], [[-100, 100, -100], [100, 100, -100]], [[100, 100, 100], [100, 100, -100]], [[100, -100, 100], [100, -100, -100]], [[-100, -100, 100], [-100, -100, -100]], [[-100, 100, 100], [-100, 100, -100]]]

#rest of the programme
```

Comment: You're unclear: "second code makes the rest of the programme to work but the second doesn't." Should one of those be "The first one"?

Comment: The problem is that the value that is printed at the end of the first code is the same as the one I assign at the end of the second. So the value of polygon should be the same at the end of the codes. Yet for some reason the rest of the code acts differently

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately it may depend on the rest of the code, I'm unable to reproduce a difference between the two scripts. If I set the furst to append to `polygon1` and the second to append to `polygon2`, then `print(polygon1==polygon2)` prints `True`

Comment: Not a good idea to use profanity in your code. But if you do choose to, please do not include it in your questions here.

Comment: Do you use any of the other variables (``p``, ``bob``, ...) in the rest of your program? They share elements with ``polygon`` and modifications may affect all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: The first variant has shared references between your data, the second does not.

---

Neither `list` literals nor equality express sharing of elements with other data structures. Two objects having the same literal or being equal still allows for them to have different shared data. This makes a difference when you modify your objects:

```
 >>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
 >>> # copy by sharing elements
 >>> b = [a[0], a[1]]
 >>> # copy by literal value
 >>> c = eval(repr(a))
 >>> a == b == c
 True
 >>> a[1].append(7)
 >>> a == b  # b shares data with a
 True
 >>> a == c  # c shares no data
 False
```

In your case, the first `polygon` shares its data with your other lists. The second `polygon` created from a literal only includes new objects:

```
# share objects with polygon
for pearJuice in p: polygon.append(pearJuice)
for pearJuice in bob: polygon.append(pearJuice)
for pearJuice in q: polygon.append(pearJuice)
# create new objects for polygon
polygon = [[[100, 100, 100], [100, -100, 100]], [[100, -100, 100], [-100, -100, 100]], [[-100, -100, 100], [-100, 100, 100]], [[-100, 100, 100], [100, 100, 100]], [[100, 100, -100], [100, -100, -100]], [[100, -100, -100], [-100, -100, -100]], [[-100, -100, -100], [-100, 100, -100]], [[-100, 100, -100], [100, 100, -100]], [[100, 100, 100], [100, 100, -100]], [[100, -100, 100], [100, -100, -100]], [[-100, -100, 100], [-100, -100, -100]], [[-100, 100, 100], [-100, 100, -100]]]
```

If you need to modify `q`, `bob`, `p` and `polygon` separately in your program, remember to `copy.deepcopy` them.

Comment: Thankyou, I used copy.deepcopy on every variable in this part of the programme and everything works fine now.